# Concatenating rows from a stored procedure onto another table in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, string-concatenation

I have a table which contains lots of NULLs in the email field. What I need to do is updating all the NULL rows. For every NULL row, I need to execture a stored procedure which basically gets all the emails related to that user's ID. Therefore, for every NULL row, this stored procedure is called and all the email fields found within this stored procedure need to be concatenated together and inserted in place of the NULL email field from the other table.

Anyone knows how to implement this in TSQL?

Many thanks in advance

EDIT:

I have found this code:

```
WITH Ranked ( CategoryId, rnk, ProductName )  
             AS ( SELECT CategoryId,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY CategoryId ),
                         CAST( ProductName AS VARCHAR(8000) ) 
                    FROM Northwind..Products),
   AnchorRanked ( CategoryId, rnk, ProductName )  
             AS ( SELECT CategoryId, rnk, ProductName 
                    FROM Ranked
                   WHERE rnk = 1 ),
    RecurRanked ( CategoryId, rnk, ProductName ) 
             AS ( SELECT CategoryId, rnk, ProductName 
                    FROM AnchorRanked
                   UNION ALL 
                  SELECT Ranked.CategoryId, Ranked.rnk,
                         RecurRanked.ProductName + ', ' + Ranked.ProductName
                    FROM Ranked
                   INNER JOIN RecurRanked 
                      ON Ranked.CategoryId = RecurRanked.CategoryId 
                     AND Ranked.rnk = RecurRanked.rnk + 1 )
    SELECT CategoryId, MAX( ProductName ) 
      FROM RecurRanked
     GROUP BY CategoryId;
```

However I can't get it to work in my case.

Basically, instead of using the stored procedure I can simply use the select statement to get one row with all the necessary emails. What I essentially need to do is to concatenate these returned emails into one row.

Comment: How does your stored procedure returns the emails?

Comment: I am trying from this link: http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/rowconcatenate.aspx but I can't get it to work. @Lamak The stored procedure simply returns a list of rows with the emails

Comment: must it be a stored proc? a UDF would be more usable here, since it can be invoked inside a TSQL statement

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a recursive Common Table Expression. But it is very difficult to suggest an exact solution without any sample data/table structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this: http://geekswithblogs.net/nagendraprasad/archive/2009/03/13/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-row---sql-server.aspx

Convert multiple rows into one row - SQL Server
As I need to send email to many people, i need to convert multiple emails into a single row delimited by semi-colon(;), i had lots of solutions, but which is an old type of solution which needs more lines of code. As i want to use one or two line code which would resolve, i found three methods for my solution which is very simple.

Method 1:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(4000)
SET @str = (SELECT CONTACT_EMAIL + ';' FROM table FOR XML PATH(''))
SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str,1,LEN(@str)-1)
SELECT @str
```

Method 2:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(4000)
SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + ';', '') + CONTACT_EMAIL FROM table 
SELECT @str
```

Method 3:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(4000)
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF( (SELECT CONTACT_EMAIL + ';'   from table FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
SELECT @str
```

Multiple rows returned:

```
CONTACT_EMAIL
abc1@domain.com
abc2@domain.com
abc3@domain.com
```

3 row(s) affected.

After executing one of the methods, i got the result as

CONTACT_EMAIL

```
abc1@domain.com;abc2@domain.com;abc3@domain.com;
```

1 row(s) affected.

Comment: @Chris - no problem but thank google more.  A simple search for "Convert rows into single row in sql server" yielded this as a result.

Comment: Yes I googled but I found more complex solutions as I mentioned in the post which varied from what I was trying to do.